# PHP json_decode error - Mandrill Webhook

Tags: php, arrays, json, mandrill

Im trying to handle Mandrills webhook data.
I will get a $_POST request with some Json Data, while handling these data i got a strange problem.

If I decode the Data given by POST, I just get an empty var :(
Any idea why?

EDIT:

the strangest thing ever ... If I use the Json directly it doesnt work, but if I insert it into the Database and take it from there, it works perfectly

```
$json = $_POST['mandrill_events'];
print_r(json_decode($json,true));
//False

$data['content'] = $_POST['mandrill_events'];
$id = $db->insert('mail', $data);
$get = $db->select('content', 'mail', 'id = "'.(int) $id.'"');  //= mysql_fetch_array($data,MYSQL_ASSOC)
$json = $get['content'];
print_r(json_decode($json,true));
//True
```

Old Code

```
/*
print_r($_POST) 

Array
(
    [mandrill_events] => [{"event":"inbound","ts":1393490345,"msg":{"raw_msg":"Received: from"}}]
    (shortend)
)
*/

$test_var = '[{"event":"inbound","ts":1393490345,"msg":{"raw_msg":"Received: from"}}]';

$getMessage = $_POST['mandrill_events'];
print_r($getMessage);
//Until now everything works fantastic
$getMessage = json_decode($getMessage,true);
print_r($getMessage);
//Nothing - the output is empty ;( 

$getTestMessage = json_decode($test_var,true);
print_r($getTestMessage);
//works fine
```

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($getMessage,true)); ?

Comment: var_dump($getMessage) == true / var_dump(json_decode($getMessage,true)) == false

Comment: echo json_last_error_msg() after jsone_decode() method call.

Comment: I've tried this code on my own server, and everything works..

Comment: Ask for an example text file from the mandrills webhook data, and paste that here to validate: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: the json is correct and if i use it directly it works quite well - the only Thing which wont work is to use it on the fly from the POST data :(

Comment: Try this: $getMessage =(json_decode(utf8_encode($_POST['mandrill_events']), true));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use stripslashes. 
In your case:

```
$json = $_POST['mandrill_events'];
print_r(json_decode(stripslashes($json),true));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented like this it can be working fine to me plz check this one

```
      $data = $_POST;

    $restult_data_decode = json_decode($data['mandrill_events']);


   // print_r($restult_data_decode);
    //exit;




    $message_id     =  $restult_data_decode[0]->_id;

    $status         =  $restult_data_decode[0]->msg->state;

    $reject_reason  =  $restult_data_decode[0]->msg->reject;


    echo "message_id............ $message_id  .............status:$status..........reject reason : $reject_reason ";
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have magic_quotes turned on on your server. This should work:

```
 $events = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['mandrill_events']),1);
 print_r($events);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print POST data it echos as html. May be in your POST Data there are `&#34;` or `&quot;` are coming inplace of double Quotes. Check that.

Comment: I just double-checked it but ist exactly like the Array posted above - nothing added or removed ;(